# Post request not functioning in a while loop

Tags: php

On my forgot password you enter your email and it generates 2 tokens one is a token and one is a reset token

this is the link sent to the email

http://example/user/password-reset/578846722?token=5e19641a37208577509eff40f91a6e66cfc5a8985c3ed5323456b83041970a4d

**Reset token 578846722**

**Token 5e19641a37208577509eff40f91a6e66cfc5a8985c3ed5323456b83041970a4d**

Once the link is clicked it takes them to a password page where the password and confirm password inputs are. on the page my password reset function is called like this

```
<?php password_reset();?>
```

When the page is brought up the first check is to make sure the token and reset token match user which the do

the page should allow the user to enter a new password with a confirm password and do an update after the form checks are made. but it ignores the password checks all together

```
function password_reset()
{
    if (isset($_GET['reset_token'], $_GET['token']) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET")) {
        $db = DB_CONNECT();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT email, confirm_code, reset_token 
        FROM users 
        WHERE confirm_code = ? AND reset_token = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_GET['token'], $_GET['reset_token']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0) {
        set_message("Unable to locate account with provided data.", WARNING);
        redirect_to_url("/user/login");
    }

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") && $_POST['password'] === $_POST['confirm_password']) {
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];

            if (empty($password)) {
                $errors[] = "Password required.";
            }
            if (empty($confirm_password)) {
                $errors[] = "Confirm Password required.";
            }
            if (!empty($errors)) {
                echo form_errors($errors[0], DANGER);
            }
        } else {
            echo "Updated";
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Show us the `form_errors()` function. Is the first parameter a string or an array. It seems strange that you populate an array and then only pass the element indexed 0

Comment: You can check these things: both `$_POST['password']` and `$_POST['confirm_password']` might not be set (do a `isset()`), also if `$_POST['password']` and `$_POST['confirm_password']` are different you'll echo "Updated". And post the `form_errors()` if possible

Comment: If it is a link that they click then how do you expect the `$_POST` values to be populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will never reach the `if` inside the `while` since you put it inside the first `if` that checks if the `REQUEST_METHOD` is GET while the other check if `REQUEST_METHOD` is POST.

That's why it is echoing "Updated" when the page comes up. Because it is a GET request, then inside the while it expects a POST, which is false, then the else says **echo updated**.

But when you send the form, which is a POST request, it will not even get inside the first `if`.

Try this:

```php
function password_reset()
{
    // if you need a get response using the same route/function, you can do it like
    //
    // if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET") {
    //     // do your stuff
    // }
    if (isset($_GET['reset_token'], $_GET['token']) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST")) {
        $db = DB_CONNECT();

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT email, confirm_code, reset_token
            FROM users
            WHERE confirm_code = ? AND reset_token = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_GET['token'], $_GET['reset_token']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0) {
            set_message("Unable to locate account with provided data.", WARNING);
            redirect_to_url("/user/login");
        }

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
                $errors[] = "Password required.";
            }
            if (empty($_POST['confirm_password'])) {
                $errors[] = "Confirm Password required.";
            }
            
            if (!empty($errors)) {
                echo form_errors($errors[0], DANGER);
            }
            else if ($_POST['password'] === $_POST['confirm_password']) {
                echo "Updated";
            }
            else {
                // case password is different from confirm_password, do your error stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that did it thank you so much